# STM32 FreeRTOS, How To Clear Task Signal Flag

Tags: task, signals, stm32, reset

I have a task that handles several operations by the id of signal flag.

Those flags don't reset at the end of the operation ( it's running in an infinite loop and waits for the next signal).

```
    for(;;)
    {
        signalWaitEvent = osSignalWait(0, osWaitForever);

        
        if( signalWaitEvent.value.v == 0x10 )
        {

              // Some magic

        }
        else if( signalWaitEvent.value.v == 0x15 )
        {
           // Some magic
        }
    }
```

As I not from the STM form, the osSignalClear function wasn't implemented.

Is there any way around it?

Thanks all!

Comment: Use freeRTOS mechanisms instead of those stupid CMSIS ones. It uses semaphore in the background so what you want to "clear"?

Comment: Hi, thanks. The value from task  doesn't change, event.valve.v from                                                          osEvent event = osSignalWait(0, osWaitForever);

Comment: Instead of this stupid CMSIS use efficient freeRTOS direct to task notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks  0___________

I replaced the CMSIS function osSignalWait with FreeRTOS ulTaskNotifyTake and it's working now.

Comment: As I said do not use this CMSIS wrapper crap